# Elegant way to get all ManagedThreadId's of a running process ( not os-thread id's)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I was looking around a little bit but as it seems, there is only one way, to get all managed thread id's, of the threads which a process starts: Obtaining them after start of a thread and then putting them into a global list.

I still would like to know, if someone knows a method, which I can use everywhere at runtime, which returns all the managed thread id's, which my process has currently running.

Comment: WinDbg/SOS can show you the managed ids. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to have them at runtime, to log and count them programatically.

Comment: That much I figured, but why do you want to do that? You app is starting all the managed threads in the process, so you should know what threads are running. The managed id doesn't tell you a lot, so I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I read, that the os threads are not necesarry linked to the clr threas, which i spawn, so i assume , that if i start a bgworker or a thread, i will not see them ine the CurrentProcess.Threads list. If i will see them, well ok, then i continue with those, but if not, i just want to have a detailed thread logging.

Comment: With the current CLR a managed thread is always tied to an OS thread. The concept of a managed thread is just a container around a real OS thread at the moment.

Comment: At least one CLR implementation is able to host multiple managed threads
in a single OS thread: the CLR in SqlServer (using
fibers, this made [AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getcurrentthreadid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) obsolete).

Comment: Nice,  but i think, this thread is dead. I found what i need.